# Given a GeoCoordinate how do I get the new Latitude Longitude after n seconds

Tags: c#, geolocation

I have a GeoCoordinate :

```
GeoCoordinate g = new GeoCoordinate();
g.Latitude=32.9116666699926;
g.Longitude=-96.6274999999863;
g.Course = 8;
g.Speed=1000;
```

Is there any way to get the new Longitude and Latitude after n seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html, there are many beautiful functions to calculate "geo-things"... Look under `LatLon.prototype.destinationPoint` . It is javascript but it converts 1:1 to C#.

```
// input values
double lat = 25; // decimal degrees
double lon = -10; // decimal degrees
double bearing = 30; // decimal degrees
double distance = 1240.8 * 1000; // meters

// constant
const double radius = 6371e3; // meters

// calculation

// see http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm#LL

double δ = distance / radius; // angular distance in radians
double θ = bearing / 180.0 * Math.PI;

double φ1 = lat / 180.0 * Math.PI;
double λ1 = lon / 180.0 * Math.PI;

double φ2 = Math.Asin( Math.Sin(φ1)*Math.Cos(δ) +
                    Math.Cos(φ1)*Math.Sin(δ)*Math.Cos(θ) );
double λ2 = λ1 + Math.Atan2(Math.Sin(θ)*Math.Sin(δ)*Math.Cos(φ1),
                         Math.Cos(δ)-Math.Sin(φ1)*Math.Sin(φ2));
λ2 = (λ2+3*Math.PI) % (2*Math.PI) - Math.PI; // normalise to -180..+180°

// output values
double lat2 = φ2 * 180.0 / Math.PI; // decimal degrees
double lon2 = λ2 * 180.0 / Math.PI; // decimal degrees
```

Clearly `distance = speed * time`.